# Select2 click specific option on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to trigger a click on a specific option on page load with Select2. I'm getting a URL parameter e.g. car and I need to click on the option in the select2 with the value of "car"

```
   let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
   let sourceid = params.get('dynamiccontent');

   if(sourceid == 'car'){
       alert('yes');
   }
```

This code above works so far because it's alerting.

I need to trigger that click in the if statement. I've tried using

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     $('.mySelect option[value="car"]').trigger('click');
     $("select.select2-hidden-accessible option[value='sustainability']").trigger('click');
     $('.mySelect').val('car').trigger('click');
     alert('clicked');
  }, 1500)
```

Comment: Do you need to actually click on the element, or are you just trying to make it the default selected option?

Comment: Handling click events on options is something that should be avoided. If you need this to trigger the same action as it would if the user manually selected an option - then set the option selected via your code, and trigger the appropriate event after: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Comment: I need to click the option because it runs an ajax function that filters content

Comment: If *your* code runs ajax on `click` then your code should be changed so that it can be run without needing a click - ie move the ajax part out of the click handler into its own function.  Then you can do `$(".mySelect").val("car").trigger("change"); myFunctionToUpdateOnSelectionChange();`   (trigger.change as it's select2)